# How do I add a rigidbody to an object with python?

Tags: python, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

The only method I could find was to use an operator which seems more like a workaround than a solution.

Comment: Could you clarify? Add a rigid body object to the mesh, or add rigid body properties to the mesh? More information is better, and you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: I meant a rigid body object to an object in the scene, though adding properties to the rigid body would be helpful too

Comment: The answer for 2.8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136687/how-do-you-enabled-rigid-body-physics-for-a-given-object-in-blender-2-8/136688#136688

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will add rigid body to the object (add the object to the rigid body group of the scene)

```
C.scene.rigidbody_world.group.objects.link(C.object)
```

as *zeffii* pointed this assumes that a rigid_body_world has been created, which is done with `bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add()`

Comment: This seems to assume that the rigid body world has been enabled. Which might not be the case until the .ops is used at least once. Else rigidbody_world is `None`

Comment: @zeffii yes, I'll add that in

Comment: I got this error: RigidBodyWorld object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 0):

Select an object and make sure no other object is selected (deselect them if that is the case), then run the following script to add a rigid body to the object of your choice.

I found this out by hovering my mouse over the 'Rigid Body' button... the tool tip is 'bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add()'

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add()
bpy.context.scene.objects.active.rigid_body.type=True # Set to False for Passive objects
```

Comment: In the question I did specify that I wasn't looking for an operator as http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/info_gotcha.html seems to imply that operators shouldn't be used in scripting with "Blender’s operators are tools for users to access" or at least that was what I thought it implied when reading previously

Comment: So you did.  I've done some more searching, but came up with no solution.  It appears that via python, the 'rigid_body' component of an 'object' is readonly. (http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object.rigid_body#bpy.types.Object.rigid_body)