# Script to add rigid body to object in scene?

Tags: python, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to write a script to add rigid body objects to all objects in the scene. I found this question helpful: [How do I add a rigidbody to an object with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/how-do-i-add-a-rigidbody-to-an-object-with-python)

But when I try the solutions I get a 'context is incorrect' error. I have tried changing the context: `bpy.context.area.type = "VIEW_3D"` but I still get the error. What is the correct context?

Comment: Which operator is giving the error?  You need to have a context.object or context.selected_objects  to use rigidbody.object(s)_add

Comment: `bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add.poll()` failed. I am unclear as to what I need to do with the context in order to add the rigid body world and the rigid body objects, and the documentation I've read has been confusing.

Comment: You might find the script in my question helpful: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49290/context-problem-with-rigid-body I am stuck in a different place there, but adding a rigid_body works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
candidate_list = [item.name for item in bpy.data.objects if item.type == "MESH"]
for object_name in candidate_list:
    bpy.data.objects[object_name].select = True
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_add(type='ACTIVE')
```

In the loop it selects all the objects that you want to add `rigid_body` to. Then add them in one go.