# How do you enable rigid body physics for a given object in Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I'd like to enable the rigid body settings for a set of objects, and I don't want to use `bpy.ops.rigid_body.object_add()`. I see that objects have the property `object.rigid_body`, which is [read-only](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=rigid_body#bpy.types.Object.rigid_body). So how do I create the rigid body settings, and assign them to `object.rigid_body`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is related to [How do I add a rigidbody to an object with python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21643/how-do-i-add-a-rigidbody-to-an-object-with-python).

In 2.8 you need to use collections, so if you want to add rigid body physics to object `my_object` for scene 'Scene':

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(my_object)
```

and verify outcome with

```
my_object.rigid_body is not None
```

Comment: @batFINGER I updated the variable name to `my_object`. Thanks.

Comment: Finally, the right answer! The accepted answer to the linked question is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have changed recently in 2.90, and I could only find a workaround by talking to folks in discord. Here's a complete snippet for code that works to create rigid body objects in Blender:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=2, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 5), scale=(1, 1, 1))
suz = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=10, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
plane = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add()
sc = bpy.context.scene
sc.rigidbody_world.enabled = True

collection = bpy.data.collections.new("MyTestCollection")

sc.rigidbody_world.collection = collection
sc.rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(suz)
sc.rigidbody_world.collection.objects.link(plane)

plane.rigid_body.type = 'PASSIVE'
```