# Exception access violation n python loop after many successful loops

Tags: python, baking, error

I have a python script which generates low poly rocks and drops them into a container using rigid body physics. In order to restrict the polygon and object count, I am creating 1000 of these at a time, joining them and then dropping another 1000 in etc. My code has worked well for smaller cases but has repeatedly crashed for cases where I want to drop a large amount of rocks (i.e increasing the number of loops below).

I get the following error during the baking sequence (i.e I get a print out of bake:frame x :: y and then this, note: its not at the last frame, so I suspect the issue is in the baking.

```
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF76A85F4CE
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00002f4c
```

There are functions called in the loop below, but the script works for multiple cases (up to 30 iterations), hence I believe the issue probably lies in the loop shown below. The script usually crashes after 30 or so iterations, and I have tested this on two machines at 16GB and 64GB RAM both using blender 2.90.

```
 for i in range(40):
    print(i)
    container_genration(Xmax,Ymax,Zmax,Xpos,Ypos)
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.time_scale = 1
    bpy.context.scene.gravity[2] = -35
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.steps_per_second=150
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.solver_iterations=250
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_start = 1
    bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_end = endframe1

    nop60=12.0846
    nop50=33.2326
    nop40=193.353
    nop30=386.707    
    nop20=374.622
    nop10=0
    nop05=0
    noparticles=nop60+nop50+nop40+nop30+nop20+nop10+nop05

    rockgenerator(noparticles,1000,Xpos,Ypos,Xint,Yint,nop60,nop50,nop40,nop30,nop20,nop10,nop05)
    override = {'scene': bpy.context.scene,
            'point_cache': bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache}
    bpy.context.scene.frame_current = endframe1
    bpy.ops.ptcache.bake(override, bake=False)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(endframe1)

    selobj=[]
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if obj.name.startswith("Low"):
            if obj.matrix_world.translation[0]>(Xpos-Xint) or obj.matrix_world.translation[0]<Xpos:
                if obj.matrix_world.translation[1]>(Ypos-Yint) and obj.matrix_world.translation[1]<Ypos:
                    if obj.matrix_world.translation[2]>0 and obj.matrix_world.translation[2]<Zmax: 
                        obj.select_set(True)
                        bpy.ops.object.visual_transform_apply()
                        selobj.append(obj)
    for obj in selobj:
        obj.select_set(state=True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.object.join()
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_remove()

    objs = bpy.data.objects
    objs.remove(objs["Cube"], do_unlink=True)
    objs.remove(objs["Cube.001"], do_unlink=True)
    objs.remove(objs["Cube.002"], do_unlink=True)
    objs.remove(objs["Cube.003"], do_unlink=True)
    objs.remove(objs["Cube.004"], do_unlink=True)

    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        if  obj.location[2]<=0 or obj.location[2]>=Zmax or obj.location[0]<=0 or obj.location[0]>=Xmax or obj.location[1]<=0 or obj.location[1]>=Ymax:
            obj.select_set(True)
        else:
            obj.select_set(False)
    bpy.ops.object.delete() 

    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
    bpy.context.object.rigid_body.type = 'PASSIVE'
    bpy.context.object.rigid_body.collision_shape = 'MESH'
    bpy.context.object.rigid_body.mesh_source = 'FINAL'
    bpy.context.object.rigid_body.use_margin = True
    bpy.context.object.rigid_body.collision_margin=0
    bpy.context.object.rigid_body.linear_damping = 0.98
    for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
        obj.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_settings_copy()
```

Please note that container_generation produces the 5 cubes which are later removed, the rock_generator module produces the rocks and assigns their rigid body properties.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have seen that this error is usually associated with trying to access an object from memory which is no longer there. I cant see that here but I may be wrong (still relatively new to python and blender).

Comment: Hard to say from a glance but I see you are removing objects by name `objs["Cube"]` If you do it multiple times this can cause a crash if Blender can't find it because the name is different or the object is gone.

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is possible, but would be surprising as the cubes are replaced at the start of each loop in container_generator. Not quite sure why this would work 30+ times and then not. Also not sure if there is anything to make out of the script failing during baking

Comment: `objs["Cube"]` will throw a keyerror if it no longer exists. An issue is often keeping a reference to an object that is since removed.  Appears to be some reduntant loops.  Would also consider replacing a lot of the operators above eg https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136687/how-do-you-enable-rigid-body-physics-for-a-given-object-in-blender-2-8