# low level alternative to bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add()

Tags: python, physics

What is the non context depended way for adding physics to blender scene ?

at the moment i`m forced to select a scene and then use the ops function:

```
bpy.context.window.scene = bpy.data.scenes['Some_Scene']

bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add()
```

thank you.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/136688/53513

Comment: Nope - that not an alternative but thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.  `world_add` ends up calling a C routine [`BKE_rigidbody_create_world`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/rigidbody.c#L1136) that is not otherwise exposed through the `bpy` API.

You would have to select a scene even if the C routine had a Python interface, because the rigid body world is attached to a specific scene, and the caller of the C routine would have to know which one.

If you wanted to add a rigid body world to a specific scene and didn't want to change the context, you could use a [context override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context):

```py
override = {
    'scene' : bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
}

bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add(override)
```

replacing 'Scene' with the name of the scene you wanted to add the world to.

#### 3.2 Update

Context overrides are deprecated in Blender 3.2 and are scheduled to be removed in Blender 3.3  The replacement is [`temp_override`](https://docs.blender.org/api/3.2/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override). The manual has examples of how to use the new function.

Comment: Thanks mate,
I can reference the scene as object - why it should be active ?
and if i must,it brings me to write this question
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265266/how-to-set-active-scene-with-bpy-context-window-scene-thru-headless-mode

Do you think blender guys will change this design limitations in the future ?

Comment: It doesn't always have to be active. You might be able to use a [context override](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) in the call. Not every bpy op allows context overrides, but this one might.

Comment: Same None :-( or maybe i do somthing wrong.
using  bpy.context.copy() 
gives
{...'window': None, 'window_manager': bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan'], ... }

Comment: @barakooda I updated the answer to show how to do it with an override.

Comment: Thanks mate!
This override trick really helps !
will use it more.