# How to set active scene with bpy.context.window.scene thru headless mode

Tags: python

I`m try to set active scene thru python code that runs from cmd.
bpy.context.window is always None in this case.

Can someone please explain why and if there is other ways
to set active scene ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to set the active scene is

```py
bpy.context.window.scene = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']
```

replacing the right hand side of the assignment with whatever scene you want to use for the new context.  See the [Window](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html#bpy.types.Window) page for details on the window type.

Comment: bpy.context.window is always None in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets None when using bpy.context.window
consider use this solution:

```
def get_context_window():
   for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
      if window:
         return window
   
   return None

import bpy

window = get_context_window()
scene = bpy.data.scenes.get('some_scene')

window.scene = bpy.data.scenes.get(scene)
```